# In how many months more products sold than bought

Tags: excel

[image]

In Excel I have 2 tables.

The first table contains product name and empty column which is called `say` (count).

And in the second table, I have date, product, transaction (sold (`satis`) / or bought (`alis`)), and count of transactions.

I need to fill the empty column `say` (count) with the count of the months in which more product was sold than bought.

End goal is to find "How many months are there when more products are sold than bought (`alis` is bought, `satis` is sold).

1st column of the first table and the second column of the second table are product names.

I tried to find the correct code which would work for me. However due to my lack of experience, I couldn't solve the problem.

Comment: yes thanks. thats the exact place where i get the error. thanks for clarification. i just wonder if is it actually possible to get what i want

Answer (score 0):

SUMIFS must use ranges and `month($E$4:$E$810)` creates an array.  This is not allowed.

Use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($G$4:$G$810*($F$4:$F$810=A4)*($H$4:$H$810="Alış")*(month($E$4:$E$810)=3))
```

Comment: I am grateful for your help.thats gonna help a lot